# How to move EF modeled connection to Production?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, deployment

I am hoping this is a simple question. Feel free to roast me, just provide an answer while doing so, please.

How does one model a database in Dev with Entity Framework, then take that application to Production and change the connection to the client's database?

Background: I have sat in on a few LINQ centered Pluralsight videos with a VS Study Group. I have also gone through Bob's brief tutorial on LINQ to Entities on LearnVisualStudio.NET as part of his C# Fundamentals course.

Comment: Are you asking about config transforms, database migrations or what?

Comment: I am wondering about making the connection work on the client's system. My database will be named differently and reside in a different location than the client's. Is it a simple config change in the edmx file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know which version of Entity Framework you are using, but usually the Context object has a constructor that takes a connection string or a name for a connection string, e.g. look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) in the official documentation for `DbContext`.

What you could easily do is agree on a name for the connection string, lets say the name would be "app" and then have whoever is configuring the system use that in the `app.config` (or `web.config` if it's a web application). The name is the name of the connection string inside the `<connectionStrings>` element in the configuration file, like this:

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="app" connectionString="[WhateverYourConnectionStringShouldBe]" />
</connectionStrings>`

Now when your context is constructed, the connection string will be taken from the configuration file of the application if you use the correct constructor, i.e. `new YourDbContext("app")`.